# Rails 3.2 hangs with JRuby 1.6.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby

I've been trying to get my Rails application to work TorqueBox and one of its requirements is to use JRuby as the Ruby language variant. I've installed JRuby 1.6.6 and the gemfile seems to bundle itself properly, but when the rails server is booted up and accessed within a browser (at localhost:3000 or 0.0.0.0:3000) then the webpage hangs...

I'm not sure if this is a problem with Rails 3.2 and the rails server does start fine (doesn't show any errors within the console) and the Rails 3.2 instance does work with Ruby 1.9.2. So I think it may be something with my gem file list or perhaps something within an initializer.

Any ideas if this is a common problem?

--- EDIT ---

I'm trying to access 0.0.0.0:3000 from WebBrick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know torquebox 2.0 beta 3 is currently tested with jruby 1.6.5.1. Maybe try switching to that jruby version. Also make sure you're running ruby in 1.9 mode. To do that, create a torquebox.yml file in your rails config folder and put the below in it:

```
ruby:
  version: 1.9
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm not just yet using TorqueBox on my local machine. I'm trying to access the webserver via WebBrick.